# Can I install an L-Bracket at an angle to match the direction of the load (for a Hammock)?

Tags: hanging

I am wanting to hang a hammock on my deck from two large wood pillars (similar to those on a pergola, though these are permanent).  I cannot simply install hooks as I also need the hooks to stick out at least 6" and ideally 8-10"to keep the hammock away from a hand rail.

So my plan is to install an L bracket that would run perpendicular to the hammock ends, placing the hammock away from the pillars (and away from the fence).  But the force would then be down and pulling inside towards the hammock.  Should I install the L-bracket on a slight angle so that it resists downwards as well as inward load?  Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to use the bracket is to keep the hammock ropes at height.

Wrap each rope end around the pillars. Secure the bracket just under the ropes at the height you'd like. The brackets prevent the ropes from slipping down the pillars which will be more able to hold the hammock aloft.

Answer (score 0):

The idea that you are talking about with just a common "L Bracket" is just not going to be a safe and workable solution. The forces on the ends of a hammock are tremendous and any mounting of a the simple bracket just is not going to perform as needed. Since you are planning a long projection of 10 inches or more you are going to need to plan on a much sturdier support mechanism.

For the vertical direction you should plan for an angle member that extends from the end of the bracket down a good 15 to 20 inches lower on the post. To deal with the intense force the hammock will be trying to pull the two brackets together you will need some additional bracing that extends from the end of the bracket out in a horizontal direction. If there is a cross member already between two posts to which you attach the brackets you can place these horizontal braces in either direction under compression or tension. It may even be possible to use a light piece of cable in tension for this purpose.